# How to remove startup programs which are not listed in Add or Remove Program list?

Tags: windows-8, boot, process, task-manager

I have two startup processes, which I'm not sure what they are for. Is it normal that a PC running Windows 8 has these two processes? They look quite suspicious as their publisher is not listed at all.

In case these processes are malware, as I suspect they might be, how do I remove them? Neither of these can be found in `"Add or Remove Program"`list.

[image: task manager two unknown processes]

Comment: Your question really lacks details which are crucial for producing an answer. Please, take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask), then re-write your question to include all the information needed.

Comment: I put image link instead of image because of lack of reputation. I don't event know about it much, that's why I am not able to describe it well.. Which information do you need for that?? tell me.. I will post it..

Comment: Right click them and select details. Also right click 'Name' in column headings and select 'Command line'

Comment: @DavidMarshall Thanks for suggesting.. but I have only two option which are enable/disable and search online.

Comment: What about command line? Maybe the files are missing. Try Autoruns for more information http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902